# How to make a horizontally animating border on links when hovered?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, the goal I'm trying to accomplish here is the idea to have a horizontal navigation bar with a border that only shows when hovered and slides with your mouse over other links in the navigation bar, and moving the mouse away from the navigation bar hides the border again except for the currently active page. I have seen this somewhere, but I cannot remember where. It is similar to [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/), but without the snap. The border should just fade when nothing is hovered. I'm not very experienced with jQuery to do this, so I'm asking anyone who may have ideas, to try and explain it as simple as possible. I have tried searching for a couple days on this animation to no avail. If this is also possible in pure CSS, that would also be great, but I'm not sure it is because it depends on the movement of the cursor. Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: it is called lava menu search it you will find plugin for it

Comment: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

Comment: It's not pure css, but I made something similar in the past: http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/DuWcz/ (looking at it now, I'd say it can be done in pure css3)

Comment: @c_kick that fit the description a lot better, is any of this code universal? or is a lot of it personalized?

Comment: Not really, you should ofcourse change the id's and classes to suit your needs, but feel free to use the script!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DuWcz/4/)

Some JS FUNCTION

```
$("#example-one").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

    /* Cache it */
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine
        .width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#example-one li").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });    
    });
```